# How to port forward on Genexis Earth-4222

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I checked portforward.com, nothing there.

I have also thoroughly scanned the web interface, no luck

I have searched everywhere i possibly can for a solution, but i cant find anything.

Comment: Does [this image](https://gyazo.com/1e1004141ec252b8a20711faf6f99319) pertain to your router? If it does, then this is found in *Services > Port Forwarding*.

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Comment: I added an answer - please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is found in *Services > Port Forwarding*:

[image]